# why parameter value not pass in [httpPost]Edit controller when using tuple?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

my problem right now is that parameter value in [httPost] Edit controller does not return any value...I have suspected that because of i'm using tuple as return value. i need help on solving this issue..thanks

below are my code.

Edit.cshml

```
@model  Tuple<MyCOOEntity.CostAnalysisModel.FinishProductCompleteForm, MyCOOEntity.CostAnalysisModel.FinishProductCompleteForm>
```

.cs Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FinishProductCompleteForm objUpdateFinishProductCompleteForm, string CommandUpdate, HttpPostedFileBase[] files, string id)
{               
    FinishProductCompleteForm objFinishProductCompleteFormUpdate = new FinishProductCompleteForm();
    objFinishProductCompleteFormUpdate = FinishProductCompleteFormDAL.UpdateFinishProductCompleteFormDetails(id, objUpdateFinishProductCompleteForm);    
    FinishProductCompleteForm objRawMatDetails = FinishProductCompleteFormDAL.GetDashboardInfo(objUpdateFinishProductCompleteForm);
    var tuple = new Tuple<FinishProductCompleteForm, FinishProductCompleteForm>(objFinishProductCompleteFormUpdate, objRawMatDetails);
    return View(tuple);                    
}
```

and yes, I'm using tuple for same class(FinishProductCompleteForm) but returning different value.

Comment: You need to show your view. If its not binding, its because you view is incorrect. (but in anycase, you should never use a `Tuple`)

Comment: for Get(actionresult edit) i'm return the value using tuple and it work well..but whenever i'm click action button(httpPost) it will not carry the value...i'm not familiar in using the tuple method,maybe it is not suitable of using this method ..right? @StephenMuecke

Comment: No its not suitable. You need to show part of your view where you generate a control for a property of your model. If `FinishProductCompleteForm` contains a property (say) `string Description` then the html for that input needs to be `<input name="Description" ...>` and the only way to generate that using `Tuple` would be to write it manually - you certainly could not use the html helpers. In any case, what is be the point of sending 2 identical classes to the view since when you only post back one? As always use a view model.